# android snapchat login kit's LoginResultCallback doesn't work normally

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, snapchat

I implemented the snapchat login in my Android app by referring to the [snapchat login kit sdk guide](https://docs.snap.com/snap-kit/login-kit/Tutorials/android#initiate-login-with-snapchat).
I refer to the below code that uses a custom button.

```
// Get the login API
SnapLogin snapLogin = SnapLoginProvider.get(getContext());

View yourButtonView = findViewById(...);
yourButtonView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Start token grant
        snapLogin.startTokenGrant(new LoginResultCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                // Here you could update the UI to show login start
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NonNull String accessToken) {
                // Here you could update the UI to show login success
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull LoginException exception) {
                // Here you could update the UI to show login failure
            }
        });

    }
});
```

1. Call startTokenGrant api to complete authentication in snapchat.
2. After authentication, callback is called when returning to my app.

Step 1 goes well.
But intermittently, the callback is not called.
I thought this was an error in the sdk, but I saw that it works normally in other apps.
Has anyone had an experience where the callback never gets called?
If yes, please help how to solve it.
(I'm developing using dev clientId right now, will this have any effect?)

Comment: Did you review your AndroidManifest? https://docs.snap.com/snap-kit/login-kit/Tutorials/android#get-started

Comment: Yes. I already did it.
The problem is that the callback is called randomly. :(